# Ver manual de propiedades y metodos en visual studio code en español

Tags: vscode

Espero me puedan ayudar soy principiante y espero ser lo mas claro posible, quisiera saber si en visual studio code hay alguna extensión o algún atajo que me permita ver la especificación que hace cada método o propiedad que estoy utilizando en español.

Ejemplo:
const colores = ["azul","verde"]
colores.push("negro")// el método push agrega un elemento al final del arreglo

Necesito que me diga que lo que hace cada método o propiedad en español que voy a utilizar

Comment: Hay una Extensiond de VSC que se llama Español, que es un paquete hecho por Misocroft. Fíjate

Comment: Muchas gracias si era eso lo que necesitaba